# swaggerで空の要素を複数持つ配列を書く方法を教えてください。

Tags: array, yaml, swagger

１つのプロパティに１つの配列があり、その配列内には複数の空の要素があります。値を持っている要素もあり、空の要素と混合して１つの配列がある状態です。
これをswaggerで書くにはどのようにすればよいでしょうか？

イメージ図

```
abc:[
  ｛
     a:1
     b:2
   },{
   },{
   }
  ］
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oneOfを使うと次のように書けるかとおもいます。

```yaml
schema:
  type: object
  properties:
    abc:
      type: array
      items:
        oneOf:
          - type: object
            properties:
              a:
                type: number
              b:
                type: number
          - type: object
```

- https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/oneof-anyof-allof-not/

Comment: ありがとうございます。